# JBoss EAP 7: xa transaction warning “No security domain defined for crash recovery” even with a security domain

Tags: datasource, xa, jboss-eap-7

I have a JBoss EAP 7.1 with some XA datasource.

The datasource has a security domain:

```
                <security>
                    <security-domain>encrypted-ds</security-domain>
                </security>
```

which makes use of the encrypted-password login module (for various political reasons):

```
            <security-domain name="encrypted-ds" cache-type="default">
                <authentication>
                    <login-module code="org.picketbox.datasource.security.SecureIdentityLoginModule" flag="required">
                        <module-option name="username" value="user_name_here"/>
                        <module-option name="password" value="some_hash_here"/>
                    </login-module>
                </authentication>
            </security-domain>
```

Yet, I get those cyclic warning messages when the server has started:

```
11:25:15,506 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.tx.jbossts.XAResourceRecoveryImpl] (Periodic Recovery) IJ000904: No security domain defined for crash recovery: java:/jdbc/myDataSource
11:25:15,511 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.tx.jbossts.XAResourceRecoveryImpl] (Periodic Recovery) IJ000905: Subject for crash recovery was null: java:/jdbc/myDataSource
```

This is similar, but not the same as question [Wildfly xa transaction warning "No security domain defined for crash recovery"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24138036/wildfly-xa-transaction-warning-no-security-domain-defined-for-crash-recovery) , as here, I have a username and an encrypted password, and a security domain. I can fathom why the system would consider there is no security domain nor subject/username.

Comment: Can you write <security> element a recovery section like: 

<xa-datasource-property name="User">username</xa-datasource-property>
...
<recovery>
  <recover-credential> 
    <user-name>username</user-name>
    <password>password</password>
  </recover-credential> 
 </recovery>
....

OR
..
<recovery>
<recover-credential>
<security-domain>...</security-domain>
</recover-credential>
</recovery>
...

Comment: That would imply me adding a password there, which I can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the JBoss Vault to manage the encrypted password.
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html-single/how_to_configure_server_security/index#secure_passwords

Answer (score 1):

You can add the same security domain for recovery

```
   <recovery>
        <recover-credential>
            <security-domain>your sec domain here</security-domain>
        </recover-credential>
  </recovery>
```